# How do I account for CSV column titles and null rows when trying to import a CSV to SQL Server using PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, csv

I have a large CSV file with 5 columns, the first row being the title of the columns.  I'm trying to pass the values to a datatable using powershell that I then pass to a table-value parameter to load the data into my SQL Server instance. My SQL Server table has already been created with the 5 columns, but I am running into issues.

```
cls
#CSV variables
$csvfile = "C:\Students\test.csv"
$csvdelimiter = ","
$firstRowColumns = $true

#creating the datatable
$dt = New-Object System.Data.Datatable
$reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader $csvfile
$columns = (Get-Content $csvfile -First 1).Split($csvdelimiter)

foreach ($column in $columns) 
{
    if ($firstRowColumns -eq $true) 
    { 
        [void]$dt.Columns.Add($column)
        $reader.ReadLine()
    } else { [void]$dt.Columns.Add() }
}

# Read in the data, line by line
while (($line = $reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null)  
{
    [void]$dt.Rows.Add($line.Split($csvdelimiter))
} 

function ExecSproc
{
    param ($Conn, $Sproc, $Parameters=@{})

    $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $SqlCmd.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::StoredProcedure
    $SqlCmd.Connection = $Conn
    $SqlCmd.CommandText = $Sproc
    foreach($p in $Parameters.Keys){
        [Void] $SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@$p",$Parameters[$p])
    }
    $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($SqlCmd)
    $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    [Void] $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
    $SqlConnection.Close()
    return $DataSet.Tables[0]
}

$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "server='.';database='ActiveStudents';trusted_connection=true;"       
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

ExecSproc -Conn $SqlConnection -Sproc spInsertStudents -Parameters @{TVP = $dt}
```

These are the errors being thrown:
Exception calling "Add" with "1" argument(s): "Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table."
At C:\Scripts\ActiveStudentInsert.ps1:24 char:2
Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '' to data type int.
The data for table-valued parameter "@TVP" doesn't conform to the table type of the parameter. SQL Server error is: 245, state: 1
The statement has been terminated."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chad Miller made a [great script in the Script Gallery that outputs DataTables in a very similar way to the one you are looking to do.](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/4208a159-a52e-4b99-83d4-8048468d29dd/)

If you used his functions, then it would look something like this:

```
$dt = Import-Csv $csvfile | Out-DataTable
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a really large amount of data, I would recommend you check out the SQL [BCP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337544.aspx) command-line utility.